# A counterexample to $(A\to B)\to\forall_xA\to\forall_xB$

Tags: logic

Let $A$, $B$ be formulas and $x$ a variable. It seems like the formula
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
(A\to B)\to\forall_xA\to\forall_xB
\end{equation}
can only be derived (using the natural deduction rules) if $x$ is not a free variable of $A\to B$. However, based on my intuition, I expected that $(1)$ is derivable for all formulas and variables. Maybe a counterexample$^*$ would help to clarify my confusion.

---

$^*$By a counterexample I mean formulas $A,B$ and a variable $x$ such that

1. $x$ is a free variable of $A$ or of $B$
2. the formula $A\to B$ is true
   and
3. the formula $\forall_x A\to\forall_x B$ is wrong.

Comment: Can you rephrase what you're after? I'm not sure what would a counterexample to "$(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\forall x. A) \rightarrow \forall x. B$ is not derivable" mean. It's like asking for a counterexample to "$5$ is not composite".

Comment: @Z.A.K. By a counterexample I mean formulas $A,B$ and a variable $x$ such that $1)$ $x$ is a free variable of $A$ or of $B$, $2)$ the formula $A\to B$ is true and $3)$ the formula $\forall_x A\to\forall_x B$ is wrong.

Comment: Is that $(A\to B)\to((\forall_xA)\to(\forall_xB))$ or some other placing of brackets?

Comment: @Filippo There is no structure $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M} \models A \rightarrow B$ and $\mathcal{M} \not\models (\forall x. A) \rightarrow (\forall x. B)$. But this does not have much to do with the non-derivability of $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\forall x. A) \rightarrow (\forall x. B)$.

Comment: @Henry That is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows, let $A,B$ denote formulas, let $x$ occur free in $A,B$, and let $y$ denote some variable that does not occur in $A,B$.

To prove that $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\forall x. A) \rightarrow (\forall x. B)$ is not derivable, it suffices to exhibit a first-order language $\mathcal{L}$, $\mathcal{L}$-formulae $A,B$, and an $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ so that $\mathcal{M} \not\models (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\forall x. A) \rightarrow (\forall x. B)$. This follows from completeness: if $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\forall x. A) \rightarrow (\forall x. B)$ was derivable, it would be validated by every model.

Of course, a structure $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies $\mathcal{M} \models (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\forall x. A) \rightarrow (\forall x. B)$ precisely if it satisfies $$\mathcal{M} \models \forall y. ((A[x := y] \rightarrow B[x := y]) \rightarrow (\forall x. A) \rightarrow (\forall x. B))$$where $P[x := y]$ denotes the renaming of $x$ to $y$ in a formula $P$ which does not contain $y$.

For a sentence $P$, $\mathcal{M} \not\models P$ precisely if $\mathcal{M} \models \neg P$. So exhibiting a structure $\mathcal{M}$ for which $$\mathcal{M} \models \exists y. ((A[x := y] \rightarrow B[x := y]) \wedge (\forall x. A) \wedge \neg(\forall x. B))$$ holds will suffice as a counterexample.

Let $\mathcal{L}$ denote the usual language of arithmetic. Let $\mathcal{M}$ denote the set of natural numbers. Let $A$ denote $x = x$, let $B$ denote $x + x = x$. Then setting $y=0$, we obtain that the implication $0 = 0 \rightarrow 0 + 0 = 0$ holds, as does $\forall x. x = x$, but not $\forall x. x + x = x$.

*edit*: As I mentioned in the comments, a counterexample in the sense you mean in your edit ("$x$ occurs free in $A,B$, the formula $A \rightarrow B$ is true and the formula $\forall_xA \rightarrow \forall_xB$ is wrong") does not exist. There is no structure $M$ in which $A→B$ holds but $(∀x.A)→(∀x.B)$ fails. But this has no implications whatsoever with respect to the (non-)derivability of $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\forall x. A) \rightarrow (\forall x. B)$.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the elaborate answer. I am currently trying to understand the third paragraph. I think that in the centered equation there is a bracket missing, since there are more brackets open to the left than brackets open to the right.

Comment: Sorry about that. I corrected it once, and then overwrote it with a copy-paste in a subsequent edit. I hope it's fixed now.

Comment: Do you underdtand why a structure $(M, +, -, 0)$satisfies $M \models x + (- x) = 0$ if and only if it satisfies $M \models \forall y. y + (- y) = 0$? It's the same thing. Free variables act like universally quantified variables as far as the satisfaction relation is concerned.

Comment: More generally, if $x$ is a free variable of $A$ and $y$ is a bound variable of $A$, then $\vdash A\leftrightarrow\forall_yA[x:=y]$?

Comment: I should probably mention that I don't know what a structure is. In my lecture it was only said that a first order language is determined by its signature and that a signature consists of a set of variables, a set of function symbols and a set of relation (predicate) symbols. Then we defined terms and formulas. I had the impression that this suffices to understand your answer, hence I didn't mention this right away.

Comment: @Filippo: "if $x$ is a free variable of $A$ and $y$ is a bound variable of $A$, then ⊢A↔∀yA[x:=y]"  No, this is not true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131821/discussion-between-z-a-k-and-filippo).

Comment: In the meantime, I learned about models and completeness, so I finally have the prerequisites to properly understand your answer :) One step is not clear yet, namely the part starting with "Of course, a structure...". Is this a special case of$$M\models P\Rightarrow M\models \forall_yP[x:=y]$$i.e. "if $M\models P$, then $M\models\forall_yP[x:=y]$"?

Comment: If this is correct, I will try to prove it. However, I would appreciate a confirmation before I proceed further, because I know that there are some subtleties involved in the definition of $P[x:=y]$.

Comment: Yes, it's just a special case: use the fact you stated above, and distribute the substitution recursively. None of the subtle edge cases in "capture-avoiding substitution" should come up: there are infinitely many variables, but only finitely many variables occur in $A,B$, so you can just assume that $y$ does not occur in either.

Comment: At that time I was very confused, for example I didn't understand that there is a difference between the statement$$\vdash P\rightarrow\forall_yP[x:=y]$$from my second comment and$$\vdash P\Rightarrow\vdash\forall_yP[x:=y]$$The latter applied to the formula $P$ from the title of my question would probably have sufficed to convince me that that $P$ is "wrong", but specifying a counter-model of course provides a complete proof and is also very instructive. This discussion helped me a lot, thank you very much!